# IMFSourceResolver::CreateObjectFromByteStream returns E_NOTIMPL

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation

I tried modifying the protected player sample from Microsoft.

I implemented a custom IMFByteStream that I provide to the IMFSourceResolver, but when I give it to "him" the result is E_NOTIMPL, is this feature not implemented?!?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out since I made a quick implementation of IMFByteStream, I left a lot of methods... you guessed it... not implemented, I was not expecting them to be called, and the resolver was returning not implemented because of that.

Once I started logging all the method calls I started figuring out what the source resolver actually needs, and started to provide an implementation on that.

Even more, at first I did a very sketchy implementation of the QueryInterface, and it needs a good implementation otherwise the resolver will call the wrong methods. Once I implemented the proper queryinterface it actually started to make sense what methods were called in my component (at first it was weird to see that I gave it read capabilities and the first thing that it tried to do is to write on my stream, I was not going to implement that).

```
HRESULT FileByteStream::QueryInterface(REFIID iid, void** ppv) {
    if (!ppv) {
        return E_POINTER;
    }
    if (iid == IID_IUnknown) {
        *ppv = static_cast<IUnknown*>(this);
    } else if (iid == IID_IMFByteStream) {
        *ppv = static_cast<IMFByteStream*>(this);
    } else {
        *ppv = NULL;
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }
    AddRef();
    return S_OK;
}
```